# Execute "SVN Copy Versioned Items Here" within Powershell

Tags: powershell, svn

Within a PowerShell script I need to do the following:

Execute the "SVN Copy Versions Items Here" RMB command for copying an earlier version of File A to a later version of File A in order to compare the before / after prior to a commit.

---

I know the full path of both files, and the paths / call look something like this:

```
$fromFile = C:\trunk\v100\fileA.txt

$toFile = C:\trunk\v200\fileA.txt
```

If I execute the following command:

```
svn copy $fromFile $toFile
```

I get the following error:  `svn: E155010: Path 'C:\trunk\v200\fileA.txt' is not a directory`

I believe `$fromFile` and `$toFile` are both stored as text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. Posting solution in the event anyone comes across the same issue. The error message displayed was a red herring - it has nothing to do with a directory.

Note: In my example, the `$toFile` had been added via a Subversion Add.

Resolved in the following manner:

```
svn revert $toFile
Remove-Item $toFile
svn copy $fromFile $toFile
```

It seems like if the file is present an error is thrown. The revert and remove calls fixed this.